# Dummy variable for each first observation of a categorical variable (id) in r

Tags: r

**Question :**
I want to create a dummy variable `first` in R which is 1 if the value of a another dummy changed from 0 to 1 under the condition that it is not the first observation for an id number. The problem behind this is that I want to recognise firms which entered a market during the observed time period in a panel setting.

As an example I tried to create this with a small sample set:

```
id <- c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3) 
dummy <- c(0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1)

df <- data.frame(id,dummy)
df[,"id"]


first.dum <- function(x)  
  c( x[-1,"id"] == x[,"id"]
    & x[-1,"dummy"] != x[,"dummy"]
     & x[,"dummy"] == "1")

df$first <- first.dum(df)
df
```

The result comes like ...

```
 id dummy first
1  1     0 FALSE
2  1     1 FALSE
3  1     1 FALSE
4  2     0 FALSE
5  2     1 FALSE
6  3     1  TRUE
7  3     0 FALSE
8  3     1 FALSE
```

I think I did not understand how that dataframe manipulation really works.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is that the output you want? What's the actual question you have?

Comment: No, the output I want would be TRUE for observation 2,5 and 8 since there the dummy changed from the observation above from 0 to 1 while the id is the same in the observation above. All else should be FALSE for the first dummy. The question is why my code does not work in that way.

Comment: utser, but an id with a "1" as the initial dummy should not be TRUE? Only after a change from 0 to 1?

Comment: That is what I have in mind, yes it should not be TRUE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would approach this using `data.table` package

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, first := c(0, diff(dummy)) == 1, id][]
#    id dummy first
# 1:  1     0 FALSE
# 2:  1     1  TRUE
# 3:  1     1 FALSE
# 4:  2     0 FALSE
# 5:  2     1  TRUE
# 6:  3     1 FALSE
# 7:  3     0 FALSE
# 8:  3     1  TRUE
```

Basically we are checking per group, if `dummy` is bigger by one than the previous observation (starting from the second observation).

You can do it similarly using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(first = c(0, diff(dummy)) == 1)
```

Or using base R

```
unlist(tapply(df$dummy, df$id, function(x)  c(0, diff(x)) == 1))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like

```
df$first <- df$id == c(NA, df$id[-nrow(df)]) & 
            df$dummy > c(1, df$dummy[-nrow(df)])
```

to give

```
> df
  id dummy first
1  1     0 FALSE
2  1     1  TRUE
3  1     1 FALSE
4  2     0 FALSE
5  2     1  TRUE
6  3     1 FALSE
7  3     0 FALSE
8  3     1  TRUE
```

If you want something like your function, consider

```
first.dum <- function(x) { 
    y <- rbind(c(NA,1),x[-nrow(x),]) 
    x[,"id"] == y[,"id"] & x[,"dummy"] > y[,"dummy"]
    }
```